# Coinbase API sandbox is no longer available?

Tags: coinbase-api

The Coinbase API sandbox website is no longer online at https://sandbox.coinbase.com/ (It's a link I obtained from this page https://developers.coinbase.com/blog/2015/02/20/sandbox#). I can't find any announcement from Coinbase that they closed that service so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Anyone know anything about this? Did they move the sandbox URL to somewhere else or they just terminated the service for good?

I've checked Coinbase Pro API, but it doesn't have the feature that we want to implement in our system.

Comment: Did u solve this. it is strange that there is nothing arround this

Comment: Sadly no, my team decided that with no sandbox available, it's pointless to use Coinbase. We didn't find any alternative service yet though.